# Samsung 830 256GB ridiculously slow with SATA1

Tags: windows, performance, ssd

I'm well aware that my 6 years old laptop with it's SATA1 bus can't fully benefit the new Samsung 830 256GB SSD.
It's OK if it's the bus that caps the transfer speeds. SATA1 is fast enough for me. I bought SSD because I though it would be major improvement to my ridiculously slow 5400rpm old HDD

But for some reason I get unbelievably horrible readings from HD Tune and I'm not sure if my system was faster with my old HDD or with this.

And why on earth are the access times so high? Bus shouldn't affect them THAT much? Right?

OS: Windows 8

[image]

Comment: Something is horribly wrong. These numbers don't make any sense. This is maybe 25% of the lowest numbers I would expect to say.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty bad - even if it's not in AHCI mode I wouldn't expect it to run *this* badly.  If you had showed me this without comment and censored the name of the device I'd have thought it must be a platter drive of some sort!  What does the Samsung Magician benchmark say?

Comment: Is it possible to run other operating systems on that same machine and then run some benchmarks there? Perhaps XP or Linux

Comment: @Juha: Did you manage to make it perform better? I have the same SSD in my equally old notebook attached to SATA 1 and it's also not as snappy as I'd expect it to be... http://superuser.com/q/757889/5375

Answer (score 0):

### Samsung Magician

I've [had a similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/757889/5375) with my Samsung 830 SSD that was also incredibly slow. I downloaded latest [Samsung Magician](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html) software and let it do the the optimization for me. I set optimization for performance and it disabled some Windows features that aren't needed with SSD disks. I also enabled over provisioning and indeed performance increased dramatically even on SATA1 bus.

Access times changed from 9,8ms (for read) and 5.5ms (for write) to 0.2ms and 0.1ms respectively.

4k performance increased 30 fold.

Opening several memory intensive programs that fill up my *maxed out* RAM proves to be much better. Running Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server management and a load of Chrome and Firefox browser tabs is not much much better. I don't have to wait for Visual Studio to open files any more. It just opens them.

Try doing the same and see if it works for you.